# Excel Fit Chart Size to Series

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, charts

I have an Excel Line Chart which looks like this:

[image]

The series has values only from 275 to 500. But the chart is showing axis from 0 to 600. I want the chart to adjust the size according to the series values. Something like this should only be shown:

[image]

How can I do this?

Comment: Right-click on the Y axis to access the formatting settings.  Set the minimum value to what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right Click **Y Axis**- Select **Format Axis**...- Under **Axis options** change `Bounds` and `Units` values:

[image]